# Exception when programmatically copying content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm getting exceptions when copying content type from one web to another:

```
foreach (SPContentType destinationWebCt in destinationWeb.ContentTypes) 
{ 
    destinationWeb.ContentTypes.Add(existingWebCt); 
    destinationWeb.Update(); 
}
```

existingWebCt is the content type from another web e.g. /Site/Web. destinationWeb is the web that I wish to copy the content type to e.g. /Site/DestinationWeb.

I got the SPException that says something like content type can not be added outside of its scope.

Then I decided to replace all "ContentTypes" to "AvailableContentTypes", but then I got the SPException saying this collcetion could not be modified.

So how can I copy a content type to another web?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code appears to be incorrect. Was it pasted directly from your source or are the typos from retyping it here? It appears that existingWebCt, which is not defined in the code block, is being added to destinationWeb over and over based on the number of content types in destinationWeb. 

Just trying to eliminate the low hanging fruit (ie, incorrect code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want content type to be available in another web, then **you must have** this content type in site content types collection or any parent web that these 2 web's have in common.

You could, ofcourse, create new SPContentType instance, copy all properties and then add it to another web, but it's a whole different content type then and it's seperated - if you make changes to one CT, it won't reflect in the other. So it is no way recommended and usefull.

And AvailableContentTypes property returns all content types of current web and parent webs, but are [read-only content types](http://blog.dennus.net/2007/07/27/spwebavailablecontenttypes-or-spwebcontenttypes/) so allows no modifications.